# Do we get our down votes back if spam is removed?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

When spam is removed, do I get my down ticks back?

If not, then it is not worth down voting a spam question.

Comment: You're suppose to **flag**, not downvote

Comment: You will if you request a reputation recalculation

Comment: @YiJiang, nothing wrong with doing both. Downvotes will help the post drop out of view faster while spam flags accumulate, and may contribute to the "poor quality posts" algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Reputation is not (usually) automatically recalculated. So you won't see your score increase after the question is deleted. If you look at http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation you'll see your "real" score, which will properly account for the deleted question (you'll get your points back).

If you want your reputation recalculated, email team@stackoverflow.com or flag your question for moderator attention and ask for a recalc.

Be advised that recalcs will also *remove* points for upvoted posts that were deleted, so your score might actually go down.

Answer (score 3):

From the [meta.rpg.stackexchange post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/437/what-should-i-do-about-spam-questions/438#438):

> Don't
>
> - vote to close them; you're wasting your close votes.
> - downvote it. The user likely has no rep, and you lose a point for nothing.

Flagging is the way to go!